# objects.all(): Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Products'

Tags: python, django, object

I'm starting to learn coding in python and I wanted to create a basic "shop", I seem to get stuck on this problem where the object.all() doesn't get recognized by PyCharm, I've already tried looking at other posts and documents but nothing helped me.

I've already tried changing the way I import the "Product" class. PyCharm gives me a warning with a yellow underline under objects.all() where it says:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Product'
```

When I run the views.py code there's an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{my directory}\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Product
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

models.py code

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
```

views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Product

def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"products": products})
```

Help would be appreciated, I'm really annoyed stuck on this.

Comment: Show the directory structure and put screenshot, do you have ```__init__.py```?

Comment: It is most probably import issue. Instead of `.model` use the abosulte path in which app your models is located like this `from app_name.models import Product`

Comment: @TariqAhmed
Here's my directory structure: https://gyazo.com/f658902ac5ccb18874aa77b7b8621a6c

Comment: @Ahtisham When I try that I get a new error code:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: And did you add your app which contains `models.Product` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in your settings.py file?

Comment: @Tarquinius I think so? Here are my INSTALLED_APPS: 
`INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'products.apps.ProductsConfig'
]`

Comment: What does "when I run the views.py code" mean? Don't you run it via `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Suddenly the code started working...